# The use of parameter of websocket's object event handler

Tags: javascript, websocket

what is the use of parameter of websocket's object event handler.

e.g. webSocketObject.onopen = function(**param**){
        codes here
}

what is the use of **param** parameter in that function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it is the event. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

You can easily find out what parameters of functions in javascript are by replacing *codes here* by *console.log(param);*. Opening the console in your browser will display the javascript console output, and objects will be printed in a traversable JSON structure.